# echo $PATH not reflecting saved paths

Tags: macos, command-line, path

I have attempted to add, `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/My_Name/desktop/My_Folder`, to `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, and `.profile`. I executed the command `source ~/.bash_profile`, `source ~/.bashrc`, and `source ~/.profile` to refresh the `$PATH` and it does reflect that when I execute `echo $PATH`.

However, when I open a new terminal and execute `echo $PATH` it is unchanged.

The issue is my system (macOS Big Sur) will not recognize the updated `$PATH` when I open a new terminal unless I execute the source command every time to refresh my `$PATH`.

For context, I edited all three because I have scoured multiple sites for suggestions and have exhausted all my options.

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` show?

Comment: Try .zshrc - Mac uses zsh by default now instead of bash

Comment: ```echo $SHELL``` shows ```/bin/zsh```.

Comment: I am unsure what try .zshrc means. I am pretty new to working on the terminal.

Comment: Thanks guys I got this issue sorted out. Now to the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was using `zsh`. To change I executed `chsh -s /bin/bash` to change my shell to `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

bash and zsh use different profile files. Instead of switching your shell you can add your `export PATH` line to `~/.zshrc` for the change to take effect in zsh.